# Use only a few RestResponse fields on Model

Tags: c#, rest, deserialization, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp in my Application. After getting a response I want to create deserialze it. But I only need some properties from this response.
Response:

```
<info>
<product>
    <name>MyService</name>
    <description>WriteSmthHere</description>
    <version>0.0</version>
</product>
<environment>
    <currenttime>1970-01-00T00:00:00.000Z</currenttime>
    <host>
        <address>127.0.0.1</address>
        <mac>qwertz123</mac>
        <port>1337</port>
    </host>
</environment>
<currentsession>
    <sessionid>1234567890</sessionid>
    <user>mrsmith</user>
    <userid>0987654321</userid>
</currentsession>
<configuration>
    <externalservices>
        <service>
            <name>Service1</name>
            <address>http://localhost:9999/api/</address>
            <timeout>60000</timeout>
        </service>
        <service>
            <name>Service2</name>  
            <address>http://localhost:9998/api/</address>
            <timeout>60000</timeout>
        </service>
    </externalservices>
</configuration>
```

Model:

```
[DataContract]
public class HostInfo
{
    [DataMember(Name = "XPath-Here?? maybe 'product.name'")]
    public string Host { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Port { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

Execution:

```
JsonDeserializer deserial= new JsonDeserializer();
resultObj = deserial.Deserialize<HostInfo>(response);
```

Is there any way to acieve this, without changing my execution code, or is there no other way than parsing the response on my own?

Comment: What you currently have doesn't work?

Comment: no, all properties were null

Comment: I highely recommend using [`Json.NET`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) instead.

Comment: Even with 'JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HostInfo>(response.Content);' I didn't get a result